# Atmel Studio 6 no new and delete operators for C++

Tags: c++, avr, atmel

I am using an ATMega32 uc with Atmel Studio 6.
I have some code that contains the `new` operator.
When I try to use it, it says that it is not defined and I don't know why.

I searched for something on Google but I didn't find anything relevant yet. All I could find was pieces of code that defines the `new` and `delete` operators but I really don't wanna work this way. Also the `nullptr` is missing.

Any other solutions?

Comment: did you include necessary header file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is perfectly possible to use dynamic memory management in embedded situations - you just need to be careful how you do it. In this case, using `malloc()` and `free()` is likely easier, though to help with compatibility you may want to define them as `new` and `delete`. A good source of information on the topic is over at [AVR Freaks](http://www.avrfreaks.net/index.php?name=PNphpBB2&file=viewtopic&t=44295&start=0).

The reason these operators don't exist is simply that AVR-GCC does not fully support C++, only parts of it. This is partly due to the nature of embedded programming - some of the more advanced C++ features can rapidly chew up flash memory and RAM. The C vs C++ on embedded platforms argument is an old and often heated one, but usually comes down to the situation. Here is another [another forum topic](http://www.avrfreaks.net/index.php?name=PNphpBB2&file=viewtopic&p=457778) on the subject.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds kinda embedded stuff. It's not a rare case, that you can use only C, not C++.

Anyway, new/delete - and malloc()/free() as well - is not a good idea in embedded world. Your program must work in any circumstances. There is *no way* to fail. It's just *n.a*. You have no console nor log file to write a message, or if you have some, no one will check it, no one will handle the error. You can flash a red led indicator, but in most cases, it's not permitted, e.g. pressing brake pedal should operate the brake, not a red led diode.

You should set up fixed size pools instead of dynamically allocate/deallocate items, and you have no option to not to handle any possible input. Your code will be full of "MAX_..." defines.

Comment: Yes but I really need to instantiate some classes. I don't know their numbers so I have to instantiate them dynamically. I send through serial the pin configuration and only at that moment I will know how many (let's say) LEDs I'll have.

Comment: Pre-allocate the maximum number of things. It's like, you know, startups: fail early. If you have about 30-40 things, pre-allocate 50. If there's no memory for 50, you have to find a solution: bigger processor, less feature (less property of the object).

Comment: I thought about it but the thing is that I may have about 7 different processes on each pin and I don't have enough space for 224 instances. Right now I have only two processes implemented and they are not occupying such a big space but they are the smallest ones.